# Dense subspace in sequences space with linear and bounded operators

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $\ell^p$, with $1<p<+\infty$ and $F\subseteq \ell^p$, such that
$$F = \left\{x=(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\,:\,\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k=0\right\}$$
Prove that $F$ is a dense subspace in $\ell^p$.

It's easy to prove that $F$ is a subspace. But for the density I trying to use this *Remark* of Functional Analysis of Brezis

> Corollary 1.8 is used very often in proving that a linear subspace $F\subseteq E$
> is dense. It suffices to showthat every continuous linear functional on $E$ that vanishes on $F$ must vanish everywhere on $E$.

Actually, I know that $(e_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Shauder basis in $\ell^p$ with that for any $x=(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$
$$x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k e_k$$
And, for any $f\in(\ell^2)^*$
$$|f(x)|=\left|\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k f(e_k)\right|\leq C \|x\|$$
But I don't know how to use that $f(y)=0$ for any $y\in F$.

Comment: An alternate approach, if you're interested: show that $(x_k) \in \ell^p \mapsto \sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k$ is a discontinuous linear functional on $\ell^p$. Discontinuous linear maps have non-closed kernels, and functionals have codimension $1$ kernels (i.e. the kernel is a maximal proper subspace). If the closure of the kernel were a proper subspace, then this would be a strictly larger proper subspace containing the kernel of a functional, which is a contradiction. So, it just suffices to find sequences $(x_k)$ in the unit ball of $\ell^p$ with arbitrarily high sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A  direct method. For $y=(y_k)_k\in l^p$ and for $\epsilon >0:$

Take $n\in \Bbb N$ such that $\sum_{k>n}|y_k|^p<(\epsilon /2)^p.$

Let $y'=(y'_k)_k$ where $y'_k=0$ for $k\le n,$ and $y'_k=y_k$ for $k>n.$

Let $S=\sum_{k=1}^ny_k.$ Take $M\in\Bbb N$ large enough that $M^{(p-1)/p}>\frac {|S|}{\epsilon /2}.$

Now let $u=(u_k)_k$ where  $u_k=y_k$ for $k\le n,$ and $u_k=0$ for $k>n.$

And let $v=(v_k)_k$ where $v_k=0$ for $v_k\le n,$ and $v_k=-S/M$ for $n<k\le n+M,$ and $v_k=0$ for $k>n+M.$

We have $ u+v\in F$ and we have $$\|y-(u+v)\|=\|y'-v\|\le \|y'\|+\|v\|<$$ $$<\epsilon /2 +\|v\|=\epsilon /2+\left(\frac {M|S|^p}{M^p}\right)^{1/p}<$$ $$<\epsilon /2 + \epsilon /2.$$

Comment: In composing this, I wrote "Take $M\in\Bbb N$ large enough that ****",  and when I got to the 2nd last line I could figure out what **** should say.